# Question on selfdestruct/suicide operation to a multi-sig address

Tags: multisignature, selfdestruct

I am writing a very simple contract that does the following:

- accepts ETH
- allows the transfer of ownerships
- logs events
- suicides when goal is met

I tested it successfully with a regular account and I do see the ETH transfer to the current account owner.

The steps I have tested are as follows:

1. Creator creates contract - creator becomes owner by default in the constructor
2. I transfer ownership to another account
3. The new owner suicides the smart contract when goal is met (1 ETH in Kovan testing environment)

When I transfer ownership between regular accounts and then suicide, it works fine.

When I transfer ownership to a multi-sig wallet (3 approvers required minimum) and then suicide it, it never sends the ETH to the multi-sig address.

Does it have anything to do with the fact that the multi-sig needs 3 approvers.

Any advice on how best to approach this?

Comment: It's hard to guess the problem without seeing the code.

Comment: @smarx - what's the best wast to post the code? Any suggestions?

Comment: function changeOwner (address _newOwner) onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        owner = _newOwner;
        
        ChangedOwner(_newOwner);
        
        return true;
    }
    
    function endPreCrowsdale() payable onlyOwner returns (bool) {
        
        // This ends the contract and send all the funds to the multi-sig wallet
        suicide(owner);
        
        // Log an even that the contract is ended/suicided and the initiator address
        endOfPreCrowsdale(msg.sender);
        
        return true;
      
    }

Comment: That code looks fine. What indication do you have that the `suicide` didn't work properly? Was this on a public network? If so, can you point us to the transaction?